# Find vectors that span the kernel of $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I have the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}

and I'd like to find the vectors that span the kernel.

The book I'm reading isn't helping me understand this concept at all.

Comment: Can you find the kernel?

Comment: Which book are you refering to? @Kevin R.

Comment: You should specify the field in which the entries of this matrix live.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The kernel (or *null space*) of a matrix is the set of all vectors that are mapped to the zero vector by the matrix. So you are looking for all the solutions $(x,y)$ to the system:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 \\
        3 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
        x  \\
        y 
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
        0  \\
        0 
\end{bmatrix} \iff
\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
x+2y & = & 0 \\
3x+4y & = & 0
\end{array}\right.
$$
The only solution to this system is the zero vector: $(0,0)$.

The empty set spans the zero vector, the dimension of this kernel is $0$. A basis is thus an empty set.

---

Since this is a rather trivial case and your book isn't really helping you, I'll add an example. Consider the matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & -1 \\
        -4 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}$$
The kernel consists of the solutions to:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & -1 \\
        -4 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
        x  \\
        y 
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
        0  \\
        0 
\end{bmatrix} \iff
\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
2x-y & = & 0 \\
-4x+2y & = & 0
\end{array}\right. \iff 2x = y
$$
Here, there are an infinite number of solutions to this system, any vector of the form $(x,2x) \;,\; x \in \mathbb{R}$ is in the kernel. This means the kernel is spanned by, for example, the vector $(1,2)$ (or any non-zero multiply of this vector). The dimension of the kernel is now 1 because it can be spanned by 1 vector (any basis will consist of 1 vector).

Answer (score 1):

Generally, we know that the vector $X$ is in kernel of matrix $A$ when $AX=0$. So, we need to find the solutions of the system $AX=0$ for your given matrix. To do so, assuming $$X=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$
we have

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

and so, $ \ \ \ x+2y=0\ \ \ \ $ and $\ \ \ \ \ 3x+4y=0$. The answer is $x=y=0$.

**Simple solution for your case:**

The matrix is non-singular, and so its kernel is $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the field is $\mathbb{Q}$. The determinant of this matrix is 4-6=-2. Since the determinant is nonzero this matrix induces an isomorphism and has therefore kernel $\{0\}$

Comment: Why would you "assume that the field is Q"?  Why not R?  Of course, the answer is the same either way.

Comment: That is exactly, why I'm assuming its $\mathbb{Q}$ this gives an answer for $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ aswell. If it would be a finite field the answer would change.

Answer (score 0):

The columns are linearly independent - they span $\mathbb{R}^2$.

∴ by rank-nullity theorem, kernel =  $\{\vec{0}\}$

Comment: I'm not sure that this 2-years old question, with already 3 answers, needs a 4th answer.

Comment: I wanted to give a different perspective (4th answer) for people who are still reading it 2 years later (like you and me).